# How do I use Media Queries in the Next.js App Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, app-router

I am using Next.js 13 with the App Router and have the following client component, which uses media queries inside the javascript to display a sidebar differently for small/big screens.

```
"use client";

export default function Feed() {
    const [isLargeScreen, setIsLargeScreen] = useState(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches);

    useEffect(() => {
    window
        .matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)")
        .addEventListener('change', e => setIsLargeScreen(e.matches));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Sidebar isLargeScreen={isLargeScreen}/>
            <div>...</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now, the site loads inside the client perfectly, but since the Next.js App Router renders this component once on the server and the server has no `window` property, I will always get this error on the server (the console running `npm run dev` in local development mode):

```
error ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Feed (./app/feed/page.tsx:32:95)
> 17 |     const [isLargeScreen, setIsLargeScreen] = useState(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches);
```

I can replace the troublesome line with a if-else like this:

```
const [isLargeScreen, setIsLargeScreen] = useState(typeof window == "undefined" ? true : window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches);
```

which then results in an runtime error on the client, if the server renders the component with the state set to `true`, but the client (on a small screen in this example) renders the component with the state set to `false`:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

How can change this component so the server and client will not throw any errors?

Comment: why you are using `useEffect` hook instead of try to write css classes in `@media() {}` and then import as module in your component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a trick like a "lazy hydration" in Next.js, there is severals methods, for example:

You can create a custom Hook, by creating a new file (useIsLargeScreen?)in the hooks folder :

```
 function useIsLargeScreen() {

  const [isLargeScreen, setIsLargeScreen] = useState(false); 

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLargeScreen(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches);

    // I write this into a function for better visibility
    const handleResize = (e) => {
      setIsLargeScreen(e.matches);
    };

    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");

    mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', handleResize);

    // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener('change', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    isLargeScreen
  }
};

export default useIsLargeScreen;
```

Than you use this hook on your Feed component:

```
export default function Feed() {
  // import this hook into this component
  const {isLargeScreen} = useIsLargeScreen();

  // maybe without conditional check if you want to render this on smaller screen with different style 
  return (
    <div>
      {isLargeScreen && <Sidebar isLargeScreen={isLargeScreen} />}
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another method I think about would be import dynamically your Sidebar, like this:

```
    import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
    
    const Sidebar = dynamic(()=> import("../path/to/Sidebar"), {  //put your Sidebar component path
      ssr: false,
    })

    export default function Feed() {
    // your code...

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar isLargeScreen={isLargeScreen} />
        <div>...</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

there is also 3rd generic method to fix hydration error:

```
    export default function Feed() {

      const [ isMount, setIsMount ] = useState(false)

      useEffect(() => {
        setIsMount(true)
      }, []);

    // your code...


     return isMount ? (
       <div>
         <Sidebar isLargeScreen={isLargeScreen} />
         <div>...</div>
       </div>
     ) : <div />
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly both solutions didnt work

Comment: can you show more on the troublesome component which cause the hydration error ?

Comment: It really doesn not matter which components I use, the point is: The server cannot know if it should render the html for small or for big screens and therefore an error will occur. I guess I have two solutions: Either rely on CSS only media queries or dont use NextJS and only render the code on the client.

Comment: well if you don't want to show i guess it can't be helped, I update my answer for a generic solution to fix common hydration issue in next js.

Comment: I fixed it by dynamically importing the sidebar. This only works if you dynamically import into a server component, thats why it wasnt working at first. I will accept your answer now

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that it sometimes takes time to get the window object in client components and usually do a recursive check.

```
"use client";

export default function Feed() {
  const [isLargeScreen, setIsLargeScreen] = useState(false) //can't use window here

  const addListener = () => {
    if (window) {
      // Do whatever you need with window here...
      window
        .matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)")
        .addEventListener('change', e => setIsLargeScreen(e.matches))
    } else {
      setTimeout(addListener, 100)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    addListener()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar isLargeScreen={isLargeScreen}/>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The problem is, the html can only be rendered in one way on the server (for large screens of for small screens), so I will get a client error if the html is not matching